# What is the Ruby idiomatic way to merge two hashes of boolean values over boolean operations?

Tags: ruby, boolean-operations

Here is the goal:

```
a={a:true, b:true, c:true, d:false, e:false, g:false, h:nil,  i:nil, j:nil}
b={a:true, b:false, c:nil, d:true,  e:false, g:nil,   h:true, i:false, j:nil}
c={a:true, b:false, c:nil, d:false, e:false, g:nil,   h:nil,  i:nil, j:nil}
conjonctive_map(a, b) == c # expect to be true
```

So the question is, what is the idiomatic way to achieve that in Ruby? It doesn't have to be a a `conjonctive_map` defined method, an inline `.map` or something like that. Also having any operation implicating `nil` to return `false` would also be fine in my case, I proposed a `c` that allways end up with `nil`.

Comment: I wonder why `a.each{|k,v| a[k] && b[k]} == c` doesn't work by the way.

Comment: E.g. because `Enumerable#each` returns the receiver.

Comment: The great mystery here: why is there no key `:f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a={a:true, b:true, c:true, d:false, e:false, g:false, h:nil,  i:nil, j:nil}
b={a:true, b:false, c:nil, d:true,  e:false, g:nil,   h:true, i:false, j:nil}
a.merge(b) { |_, v1, v2| v1 && v2 }
#⇒ {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>nil, :d=>false,
#   :e=>false, :g=>false, :h=>nil, :i=>nil, :j=>nil}
```

If for some reason you want `nil` to prevail over `false`, this is to be done explicitly:

```
c={a:true, b:false, c:nil, d:false, e:false, g:nil,   h:nil,  i:nil, j:nil}
a.merge(b) { |_, v1, v2| [v1, v2].any?(&:nil?) ? nil : v1 && v2 }
_ == c
#⇒ true
```

Comment: Nice, and far better than what I came with in the meantime: `a.map{|k,v| {k => (a[k] && b[k])}}.reduce(:merge)`. I wasn't aware that merge could take a block. I also realised that actutally `&&` is not commutative: `(false && nil) == (nil && false) # false`.

Comment: you could also make the ternary a modifier instead `a.merge(b) { |_, *v| v.reduce(:&) unless v.any?(&:nil?) }`

Comment: @engineersmnky I thought about that, but I hate implicit `nil` returns from postfix conditional, when the outcome must be explicitly set to `nil` in such a case.

Comment: @psychoslave of course it’s not commutative why did you ever expect it would be?

Comment: @mudasobwa I do not disagree that yours lends much better to readability and understanding. (Honestly I just couldn't come up with any other improvement that warranted a new answer)

Comment: @mudasobwaI think I inferred it was commutative because it is so over `{true, false}`. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = { a:true,  b:true, c:true, d:false, e:false, g:false, h:nil,  i:nil,   j:nil }
b = { b:false, a:true, c:nil,  d:true,  e:false, g:nil,   h:true, i:false, j:nil }

values = b.values_at(*a.keys)
  #=> [true, false, nil, true, false, nil, true, false, nil]
a.transform_values { |v| v && values.shift }
  #=> {:a=>true, :b=>false, :c=>nil, :d=>false, :e=>false, :g=>false, :h=>nil,
  #    :i=>nil, :j=>nil}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), which made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

If only `true` and `false` are to be returned replace `&&` with `&`. See [TrueClass#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-26), [FalseClass#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-26) and [NilClass#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-26).